# React returns the Login page by default if the user isn't authenticatied if I submitted any url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a Django/React app and I use JWT authentication. The problem is that when I enter any url from any route It changes the url by default to the url of the Login page if the user isn't authenticated and I don't want this (I want it to return the Login page for certain pages not all pages).

AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const AuthContext = createContext()

export default AuthContext;


export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [user, setUser] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const history = useNavigate()

    let loginUser = async (e )=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        let response = await fetch('/token/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'username':e.target.username.value, 'password':e.target.password.value})
        })
        let data = await response.json()

        if(response.status === 200){
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            history('/')
        }else{
            alert('Something went wrong!')
        }
    }


    let logoutUser = () => {
        setAuthTokens(null)
        setUser(null)
        localStorage.removeItem('authTokens')
        history('/login')
    }


    let updateToken = async ()=> {

        let response = await fetch('/token/refresh/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'refresh':authTokens?.refresh})
        })

        let data = await response.json()
        
        if (response.status === 200){
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
        }else{
            logoutUser()
        }

        if(loading){
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    let contextData = {
        user:user,
        authTokens:authTokens,
        loginUser:loginUser,
        logoutUser:logoutUser,
    }


    useEffect(()=> {

        if(loading){
            updateToken()
        }

        let fourMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 4

        let interval =  setInterval(()=> {
            if(authTokens){
                updateToken()
            }
        }, fourMinutes)
        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)

    }, [authTokens, loading])

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData} >
            {loading ? null : children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import '../../static/css/index.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

import { AuthProvider } from "../authentication/AuthContext";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
 
  <div>
        <Router>
        <AuthProvider>
        <React.StrictMode>
      <div>
        <HomePage />
      </div>
      </React.StrictMode>
        </AuthProvider>
      </Router>
      
      </div>
  
 
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

HomePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";
import LoginPage from "../authentication/LoginPage";
import AuthorForm from "../forms/submitforms/AuthorForm";
import { AuthProvider } from "../authentication/AuthContext";
export default function HomePage() {

let {user, logoutUser} = React.useContext(AuthContext)

function authenticationButtons (){
  
  if (user){
    return(

      <p className="brand-name" onClick={logoutUser}>logout</p>
    )
  }
  else{
return(
    <div>
  
      <Link to="/login"className='brand-name' > Login.</Link>
      <a href="/register" className="brand-name">
        <span>
       Register
      </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
  
    return (

        <div className="container">
          
        <div>{authenticationButtons()}</div>
   
        <Routes>
       
           <Route exact path='/' element={<LandingPage/>}/>
          <Route exact element={ <LoginPage /> } path="/login"/>
          
          <Route path="authorform" element={<AuthorForm />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div >
    );
  }
```

when the user isn't logged in and I open the browser and open `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://localhost:8000/authorform` it redirects me automatically to `http://localhost:8000/login` and I don't want this so how can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you've a `useEffect` hook in `AuthProvider` that calls `updateToken` when mounting... this is the only place I see any code you've shared navigating to `"/login"`. I would investigate there.

Comment: Can you explain further please what can I do? @DrewReese

Comment: Check that the `authTokens` state value that is used for the `"/token/refresh/"` POST request is what you expect it to be when the app is mounted and initially rendered. It looks like if this check fails then `logoutUser` is called, which clears some state and localStorage and navigates to `"/login"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use useLocation hook to cheack if the current route requires auth :
and must update Home page :

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../authentication/AuthContext";
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";
import LoginPage from "../authentication/LoginPage";
import AuthorForm from "../forms/submitforms/AuthorForm";

const HomePage = () => {
  const { user, logoutUser } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  const authenticationButtons = () => {
    if (user) {
      return <p className="brand-name" onClick={logoutUser}>logout</p>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to="/login" className="brand-name">
            Login.
          </Link>
          <a href="/register" className="brand-name">
            <span>Register</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
  const requiresAuthentication = location.pathname !== "/login";

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>{authenticationButtons()}</div>

      <Routes>
        {requiresAuthentication && !user ? (
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/authorform" element={<AuthorForm />} />
          </>
        )}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: I have tried this but hasn't worked. When I console.log(requiresAuthentication) it returns false and !user returns null

Comment: in this way , I think the error in useEffect when call update token so in update token function check in if have token or get token after updated